# Checkbox doesn't appear checked

Tags: css, html

I'm a beginner in html (and javascript) and I'm making a project to practice what I've learned. So I'm trying to make a custom checkbox by styling it. Here's the CSS for it:

```css
input[type=checkbox]{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    outline: none;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
    background-color: rgb(168, 168, 75);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

And this is the result I get:

[image]

If I click it, nothing happens. I would be grateful if someone provided any suggestions on how I could make it work!

Note: I haven't found anything specific to my problem or any recent posts related to it on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You haven't given a working snippet. Yet, trying to find it..

Comment: Test in teh browser devtool if the checkbox gets checked or not

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I'm not sure how to work with code snippets when asking a question so see if there's something wrong with my css if you can.

Comment: @GiaFil7 That's totally fine. Check out my answer. `:)`

Comment: @Daniel Could you tell me how because I'm new to this kind of stuff

Comment: @GiaFil7 Did you check out my answer? Reload the page and check it out. `:)`

Comment: There is lots of info on the internet to find and help yourself. Read this article will help you undesrtand what you need to do. https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/pure-css-accessible-checkboxes-and-radios-buttons-54063e759bb3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
input[type=checkbox]{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    outline: none;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
    background-color: rgb(168, 168, 75);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

input[type=checkbox].type1:checked:after {
    content: '✓';    /* or '\2713', or '\2714' */
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox].type2:checked:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 60%;
    width: 30%;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-22%) rotate(45deg);
    transform: translateY(-22%) rotate(45deg);
    border-right: 2px solid red;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" class="type1" /> Test</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="type2" /> Test</label>
```

Comment: One short question: how do I type the ✓(so I don't have to copy paste it every time I need it) ?

Comment: I think you can't type "**✓**" easily, but you can type "**v**" or "**V**" instead.

Comment: @GiaFil7 You can replace `'✓'` with `\2713'` (normal check mark) or `'\2714'` (**heavy** check mark), just remember the code. _(I edited the answer.)_

Comment: @GiaFil7 I edited the answer again, there's another way (without unicode character).

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't given the `:checked` state, it doesn't work. You have to **explicitly specify** it, something like this:

```css
input[type=checkbox]:checked {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Full working snippet for you:

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
  background-color: rgb(168, 168, 75);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" /> Check me!</label>
```

Note: I have added `vertical-align: middle` so that it displays well with the text. `;)`

Comment: So now when I click it, it turns completely black (as expected). But how can I make it actually "checked"?